# upload with jqueryform and mvc

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I'm trying to upload an image file using ajaxForm(). Somehow the server never gets the request. here's some code:

```
$('form').ajaxForm({
    iframe: true,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: '/UploadPictureId',
    data: {
        academicPhotoId: $('#AcademicPhotoId')
    },
    success: function (result) {
        alert("win");
    }
});
```

and here's the method code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult UploadPictureId(HttpPostedFileBase AcademicPhotoId)
    {

        return Json(...);
    }
```

Comment: Is the url in your javascript correct?  Usually it's a two-part url, e.g., /ControllerNameHere/UploadPictureId

Comment: I also have the controller there. it should be url: '/controller/UploadPictureId',

Answer (score 0):

A few things to check:

- See my comment about making sure it's pointing to the correct URL in the first place.
- Your form should have enctype="multipart/form-data" on it.
- You may also have to set the response type to text/html as noted [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1439867.aspx)